# Avoid double scroll in navigation and in site

Tags: css

I make part of my site - div sidebar, to be navigation and full screen. But now i can scroll in this div one time and i have second (main) scroll for site.

I want to remove one of the scrolls and visitor to can scroll only in navigation div when is show.

sidebar div now have this css

```
.sidebar {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 70px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 2;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

You can see page live here [link](http://detelinmarkov.blogspot.com)

Where is my mistake? I want final result to be like [this when menu is toggle](https://wordpress.org/themes/eighties/preview/)

Thanks

Comment: can you use jquery for this??

Comment: You have your navigation formatted `position:fixed` and `overflow:auto`, so this behavior is nothing but to be expected when the content of the navigation is higher than the available space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a solution with jquery:

```
//if your side bar is visible
if($('.sidebar').is(':visible')){
$('html').css('overflow','hidden');//add css to html or body element to hide the outer scroll
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nishanth, work perfect for first toggle sidebar. When hide sidebar, scroll of main content is gone. May be need to add "else" code?

Comment: I fix it with adding:
      else{
      $('html').css('overflow','visible');
      }